# Display Current Date and Time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have to display the current date and time in the Master layout of my views.

I 've added the current date and time

```
<div class="date-time">@{
@Html.Label(string.Format("{0:F}",System.DateTime.Now))
  }
 </div>
```

The problem is need to update the time in real time.
It's not updating until I refresh the page.

Comment: You need to use JavaScript for that. See [this example](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_timing_clock).

Comment: Follow [Layouts and Sections with Razor] (http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor) in which the date time update is given clearly.

Comment: @Brainy it's working but I need to add the time to the Master Layout view. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my java script code

```
function updateClock() {

    var currentTime = new Date();

    var currentHours = currentTime.getHours();
    var currentMinutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
    var currentSeconds = currentTime.getSeconds();
    var currentDay = currentTime.getDay();
    var currentMonth = currentTime.getMonth();

    // Pad the minutes and seconds with leading zeros, if required
    currentMinutes = (currentMinutes < 10 ? "0" : "") + currentMinutes;
    currentSeconds = (currentSeconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + currentSeconds;

    // Choose either "AM" or "PM" as appropriate
    var timeOfDay = (currentHours < 12) ? "AM" : "PM";

    // Convert the hours component to 12-hour format if needed
    currentHours = (currentHours > 12) ? currentHours - 12 : currentHours;

    // Convert an hours component of "0" to "12"
    currentHours = (currentHours == 0) ? 12 : currentHours;

    // Compose the string for display
    var currentTimeString =  currentHours + ":" + currentMinutes + ":" + currentSeconds + " " + timeOfDay;

    return currentTimeString;
}
```

And the Layout file... Need to add the reference of the javascript file and I have added the bundle.

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/clock")


<script>
    function DiplayClock() {
        var currentTime = updateClock();
        document.getElementById("clock").firstChild.nodeValue = currentTime;
    }
</script>

</head>

<body onload="DiplayClock(); setInterval('DiplayClock()', 1000);">

<div class="date-time">
    <span id="clock">&nbsp;</span>
 </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

A easy way to do it is:

'document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = new Date().toDateString()'

Answer (score -1):

You have to use javascript.

First declare a timer at the beginning of your .js file:

```
var objTimer;
```

after that, you have to set the timeout interval in any initial .js function:

```
objTimer = setTimeout("DisplayDate()", 1000);
```

and then, of course, code the DisplayDate() function; something like:

```
function DisplayDate() {

    var objDate = new Date;
    var intDate = objDate.getDate();
    var intDay = objDate.getDay();
    var intMonth = objDate.getMonth();
    var intYear = objDate.getYear();
    var intHours = objDate.getHours();
    var intMinutes = objDate.getMinutes();
    var intSeconds = objDate.getSeconds()
    var strTimeValue = "" + intHours
    strTimeValue += ((intMinutes < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + intMinutes
    strTimeValue += ((intSeconds < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + intSeconds

    var strDate = intMonth + " " + intDate + ", " + intYear + " " + strTimeValue;

    document.getElementById('fcr_spanDateTime').innerHTML = strDate;

}
```

Hope it helps.