# how can show only time part only from the current datetime in html

Tags: html, asp.net-core, view

how can I show the time part only from the current datetime in html under div tag. I called the function but not calling the javascript function

```js
@section Scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
       

        function startTime() {
            var today = new Date();
            var h = today.getHours();
            var m = today.getMinutes();
            var s = today.getSeconds();
            m = checkTime(m);
            s = checkTime(s);
            document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
                h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
            var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
        }
        function checkTime(i) {
            if (i < 10) { i = "0" + i };  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
            return i;
        }
    </script>
}
```

```html
 <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <h2><b>Place</b></h2>
                <div>startTime()</div>
                     
            </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what exactly you want in o/p.

Comment: You need yo use javascript and this que is already answered on stack overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23910990/display-current-date-and-time

Comment: I  want to display just the time part of the datetime.now.  It is need not be incremented interval of the time. just want to show the time part of datetime.now

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_timing_clock try this

Comment: I tried to call the java script function still not working . I have given my code

Comment: what error you are getting when you are trying to run the snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you forget to set  `id="txt"` to the div, and don’t forget to write `onload="startTime()"` in the `<body>` ,so that the javascript can be called.

and the following is my demo,hope it can help:

View:

```
<body onload="startTime()">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <h2><b>Place</b></h2>
        <div id="txt">            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>   
</body>

@section Scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function startTime() {
            var today = new Date();
            var h = today.getHours();
            var m = today.getMinutes();
            var s = today.getSeconds();
            m = checkTime(m);
            s = checkTime(s);
            document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
                h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
            var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
        }
        function checkTime(i) {
            if (i < 10) { i = "0" + i };  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
            return i;
        }

     </script>
}
```

Result:
[image]